# How to set color of selection in EditText in my custom theme? (android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, customization, android-theme

I created my custom theme and in my layouts I have a couple of EditText views. Since I set

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

,I've noticed that the color of selection is default one for my phone, so I was wondering can I set some attribute and which, of course, in my definition of my theme to have a desired effect, i.e. set the color of selection to needed color?

Best,
Deveti

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `android:textColorHighlight` to your preferred color.