# How to change highlighted EditText color in Android?

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

I am totally new to Android and ran into the following: while using the Material Light Theme my EditText turns a shade of pink upon selection.

I searched around how to change it and found the following telling me to change the android:textColorHighlight to my preferred color:
[How to set color of selection in EditText in my custom theme? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466172/how-to-set-color-of-selection-in-edittext-in-my-custom-theme-android#)

Sadly this doesn't seem to work for me.

This is my styles.xml:

```
<!-- res/values/styles.xml -->
<resources>
    <!- theme inherits from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/lightText</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/textColorHighlight</item>
        <!-- theme customizations -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting this attribute android:textColorHighlight="@color/textColorHighlight" directly in EditText tag in your xml layout file and recheck @color/textColorHighlight is not pink

Comment: @L-X Sadly no success. Checked for the color in colors.xml as well but no mistakes there. Thanks though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it:

EditText uses the themecolor defined as: **android:colorAccent**

So:

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings:

[image]

And here's the result:

[image]